# SSRS: Is there a Limit to what you can type in a TxtBox Property?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

In the Properties for a Text Box in my report I have an Expression like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!SubCategory.Value = "Value 1:", "Snow", IIF(Fields!SubCategory.Value = "Value 2:", "Snow", IIF(Fields!SubCategory.Value = "Value 3:", "Snow", "White")))
```

It is working fine but I need to add another IIF clause to include "Value 4:".

*The values are not actually "Value 1:" ... etc - but longer descriptive names so the actual text in the Background Colour Property box is longer.*

When I try to add the text, I am not able to do so. Is there a reason I cannot add the new IIF clause to the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I found out why I was not able to edit the expression in that particular Property field.

I erroneously gave the example of the Background Color property - when I should have pasted the example from the Font Weight property.

The problem was that I had not gone specifically to the 'Font Weight' property but was trying to edit text in the 'Font' category without dropping the arrow and expanding the Font properties.

Once I expanded the Font category, I was able to edit the Font Weight property.

Apologies!